# Kubernetes Load Balancer Oracle Cloud NGINX ingress controller problem

Tags: oracle, nginx, ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

first post on stack overflow, hope i will get some help :)

I've been struggling for a while trying to get this to work.
So basically i have kubernetes cluster in Oracle Cloud.
I'm using nginx ingress controller + cert manager for certificates.

When i deployed nginx ingress controller Oracle Cloud provided me with Load Balancer.

So we come to my problem. By default Load Balancer got listeners in cloud using TCP protocol (here is pic)
[TCP Listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18IhS.png)

And in kubernetes service (nginx ingress controller) protocol is tcp also.

When this setup is used it is working all fine.

Also im using SNI (multiple service on one endpoint).

But Oracle Cloud provides WAF that can be used with only http listeners (one more pic)
[Http listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpcGR.png).
So if i intend to use WAF i need to set this http listeners on Load Balancer.

This is nginx ingress service pic where you can see protocol is TCP.
[TCP nginx ingress service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRHMf.png)

When i change listeners to http. My domain have this error "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" when i try to open it on browser.

I tried many things including changing configuration of nginx ingress controller, adding annotations etc..

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: 'true'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
```

But nothing works i always get that "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

So i don't know is this even possible, and by that i mean can there be http listeners that point on  tcp protocol (nginx ingress service)?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OCI **TCP** listeners to **HTTP** listeners backed as HTTPS or SSL passthrough.

You can first create the **self-sign** **SSL** **certificate** if you are attaching it at the **LB** level.

If you are using cert-manager and saving it into a secret that's fine you can also follow it.

You can go to LoadBalancer and change the Protocol or Listeners to **HTTP** instead of **TCP** manually and attach the certificate to **LB** on the **443** **port** if you are following that method (as i did).

Next

Go to **Nginx ingress controller svc** and edit it and change the target port for **443** to **http**

[image]

[image]

Now inside your app ingress configuration you can use the **annotations** it will work without error of `400 Bad request` or `HTTP requested on HTTPS` port

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: 'true'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
```